# Unable to start x11vnc on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS as service

Tags: services, vnc

I am trying to run x11vnc as service to start it on boot. Below is the code that I am using drawn from the two answers [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/402201/creating-x11vnc-system-service).

```
[Unit]
Description=VNC Server for X11
Requires=display-manager.service
After=display-manager.service

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/x11vnc -auth guess -forever -loop -noxdamage -repeat -rfbauth /etc/vnc.passwd -rfbport 5902 -shared
ExecStop=/usr/bin/x11vnc -R stop
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=2

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then I run:

```
 sudo systemctl daemon-reload
 sudo systemctl enable x11vnc.service
 sudo systemctl start x11vnc.service
```

On the last command, I get the following error message.

```
Job for x11vnc.service failed because a timeout was exceeded. See "systemctl status x11vnc.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

There is no conclusive answer on `systemctl status x11vnc.service` or `journalctl -xe` but I can supply if needed.

Another thing I noticed is that the ports 5900, 5901 could be open or closed in different boots. I don't know which process is taking them.

The code below works but it can't start when integrated in the service above.

When restarting Ubuntu, it works initially and stops working after few minutes.

```
exec /usr/bin/x11vnc -auth guess -forever -loop -noxdamage -repeat -rfbauth /etc/vnc.passwd -rfbport 5902 -shared
```

Ubuntu Version: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

Is there anything I am missing that prevents x11vnc from starting?

Comment: Thank you @guiverc I have updated my question and title. Do you think updating it will solve the problem?

Comment: You might want to ensure you're fully-up-to-date with packages, a fully-upgraded Xenial system will report itself as 16.04.7 (16.04.6 implies you're behind on upgraded packages & security fixes).  Do I think it'll help, NO (they'll be security fixes, which in itself is worthwhile to most of us where security matters).

Comment: I will update. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a fix but a workaround. I used `sudo crontab -e` to store run the x11vnc at startup. I just needed to add this below at the end of `crontab`.

```
@reboot exec /usr/bin/x11vnc -auth guess -forever -loop -noxdamage -repeat -rfbauth /home/geodev/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5900 -shared
```

Running it in `sudo` is important to start `x11vnc` before login of any user.

Answer (score -1):

if you have installed another version of vncserver
you'll need to remove it then reboot the machine
and start the service again